# Python: Read text file into dict and ignore comments

Tags: python, dictionary, text, comments

I am trying to put the following text file into a dictionary but I would like any section starting with '#' or empty lines ignored.

My text file looks something like this:

```
# This is my header info followed by an empty line

Apples          1                # I want to ignore this comment
Oranges         3                # I want to ignore this comment

#~*~*~*~*~*~*~*Another comment~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*

Bananas         5                # I want to ignore this comment too!
```

My desired output would be:

```
myVariables = {'Apples': 1, 'Oranges': 3, 'Bananas': 5}
```

My Python code reads as follows:

```
filename = "myFile.txt"
myVariables = {}

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('#') or not line:
            next(f)

        key, val = line.split()
        myVariables[key] = val
        print "key: " + str(key) + " and value: " + str(val)
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/test_1.py", line 11, in <module>
    key, val = line.split()
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I understand the error but I do not understand what is wrong with the code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have control on the text file format? if so maybe consider using PyYAML?

Comment: Sadly not. The text format is what I was instructed to work with.

Comment: Have you checked the answers? A few good approaches have been given. Go through them and ask if you need more info.

Comment: @ Pouria Hadjibagheri: Yes, absolutely good approaches, thank you! I am going through them as we speak :)

Comment: I found my answer. Thank you ALL for your incredibly quick and helpful responses/insights!

Answer (score 3):

Given your text:

```
text = """
# This is my header info followed by an empty line

Apples          1                # I want to ignore this comment
Oranges         3                # I want to ignore this comment

#~*~*~*~*~*~*~*Another comment~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*

Bananas         5                # I want to ignore this comment too!
"""
```

We can do this in 2 ways. Using `regex`, or using Python generators. I would choose the latter (described below) as `regex` is not particularly fast(er) in such cases.

To open the file:

```
with open('file_name.xyz', 'r') as file: 
    # everything else below. Just substitute `for line in lines` with 
    # `for line in file.readline()`
```

Now to create a similar, we split the lines, and create a list:

```
lines = text.split('\n')  # as if read from a file using `open`.
```

**Here is how we do all you want in a couple of lines:**

```
# Discard all comments and empty values.
comment_less = filter(None, (line.split('#')[0].strip() for line in lines))

# Separate items and totals. 
separated = {item.split()[0]: int(item.split()[1]) for item in comment_less}
```

Lets test:

```
>>> print(separated)
{'Apples': 1, 'Oranges': 3, 'Bananas': 5}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly reproduce your error, but there's a problem with your code:

```
>>> x = "Apples\t1\t# This is a comment"
>>> x.split()
['Apples', '1', '#', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'comment']
>>> key, val = x.split()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Instead try:

```
key = line.split()[0]
val = line.split()[1]
```

Edit: and I think your "need more than 1 value to unpack" is coming from the blank lines. Also, I'm not familiar with using `next()` like this. I guess I would do something like:

```
if line.startswith('#') or line == "\n":
    pass
else:
    key = line.split()[0]
    val = line.split()[1]
```

Comment: I was just using next() because someone suggested it on another post. I will try and use pass instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to ignore empty lines and lines starting with `#` splitting the  remaining lines after either splitting on `#` or using *rfind* as below to slice the string, an empty line will have a new line so you need `and line.strip()` to check for one, you cannot just split on whitespace and unpack as you have more than two elements after splitting including what is in the comment:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    d = dict(line[:line.rfind("#")].split() for line in f
              if not line.startswith("#") and line.strip())
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'Apples': '1', 'Oranges': '3', 'Bananas': '5'}
```

Another option is to split twice and slice:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    d = dict(line.split(None,2)[:2] for line in f
              if not line.startswith("#") and line.strip())
    print(d)
```

Or splitting twice and unpacking using an explicit loop:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith("#") and line.strip():
            k, v, _ = line.split(None, 2)
            d[k] = v
```

You can also use *itertools.groupby* to group the lines you want.

```
from itertools import groupby
with open("in.txt") as f:
    grouped = groupby(f, lambda x: not x.startswith("#") and x.strip())
    d = dict(next(v).split(None, 2)[:2] for k, v in grouped if k)
    print(d)
```

To handle where we have multiple words in single quotes we can use *shlex* to split:

```
import shlex
with open("in.txt") as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith("#") and line.strip():
            data = shlex.split(line)
            d[data[0]] = data[1]

print(d)
```

So changing the Banana line to:

```
 Bananas          'north-side disabled'                # I want to ignore this comment too!
```

We get:

```
{'Apples': '1', 'Oranges': '3', 'Bananas': 'north-side disabled'}
```

And the same will work for the slicing:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    d = dict(shlex.split(line)[:2] for line in f
              if not line.startswith("#") and line.strip())
    print(d)
```

Comment: Hi Padraic! Your 'split twice and slice'-method worked best for me. I forgot to mention some second column values sometimes have single quotes around a string such as: 'north-side disabled'.

Comment: @SilverEyes9, shlex will take care of that for you, see the edit.

Comment: Thank you, Sir! That totally helped! The tool works!

Answer (score 0):

To strip comments, you could use `str.partition()` which works whether the comment sign is present or not in the line:

```
for line in file:
    line, _, comment = line.partition('#')
    if line.strip(): # non-blank line
        key, value = line.split()
```

`line.split()` may raise an exception in this code too—it happens if there is a non-blank line that does not contain exactly two whitespace-separated words—it is application depended what you want to do in this case (ignore such lines, print warning, etc).

Comment: Nice approach. I wouldn't have thought of `str.partition()` for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the file is correctly defined you can try a solution with regular expressions. 
Here's just an idea:

```
import re

fruits = {}
with open('fruits_list.txt', mode='r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.match("([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[\s]+([0-9]+).*", line)
        if match:
            fruit_name, fruit_amount = match.groups()
            fruits[fruit_name] = fruit_amount


print fruits
```

**UPDATED**:
I changed the way of reading lines taking care of large files. Now I read line by line and not all in one. This improves the memory usage.

Comment: Not really a good idea. There may be special characters in the text to begin with. Even if that's not the case, `regex` is not usually the best way to approach these problems as it is in fact slower than the alternatives in such cases (contrary to popular view). Average of 10k loops using this solution take 12.5 micro sec for the given text, and using my solution (Python generators), it take 8.5 micro sec. For a longer text, the difference would become much more noticeable. Something to think about?

Comment: Yea, I actually timed it on a line by line basis, since I did it on `text.split('\n')` with 'text' being the piece of string I copied from here. So my complaint persists. Though reading line by line introduced another problem (not that I think it would matter in this context); which is the fact that Python automatically closes the file after 30 seconds. So I guess another solution for large data would be to read the file in chunks and simultaneously write extracted data in a CSV or JSON. The new file would be smaller (no comments or spaces), and considerably faster to parse. Just a thought!

Comment: @PouriaHadjibagheri Where can I find information about the automatic closes problem? Is it happening still when the script reads from the file within the 30 seconds? Or just after 30 sec. of inactivity? Reading by chunks sounds good in really large files!

Comment: I genuinely don't remember where did I read / encounter that. It was a few years ago. It would make more sense if this would happen when left unused for long. Another possibility would be that I'm mixing it with a different language all together! But in any case, to be honest, if one needs 30 seconds to read a file, it's best to reconsider the methods used for handling that file!

Comment: @PouriaHadjibagheri Agree with you. My think is that if you don't keep a reference to de I/O instance, the garbage collector will remove it. In my case I use 'with' for keeping it in the context. After the 'with' block it will be automatically closed and the instance, I guess, labeled as waste.

Comment: Of course, that's always the case. And using `with` is the best practice for handling files in Python anyway. Unless when dealing with chunks (lazy), in which case it's best to do it in a loop inside a generator function using `yield file_obj.read(chunk_size)` , called from another function which handles the read chunk, returns it (so it's garbage collected), and then goes for the next one.